# What are the best ways to block ISP from spying on you

Tags: wifi, vpn, isp

My dad keeps trying to log everything I do with the WiFi, I've gotten a VPN and use HTTPS everywhere, But I'm not completely sure it worked.

Is there any other good things to use?

Or is this enough, I'm pretty sure he uses Orbi, I've already bypassed parental controls but wanna make sure he isn't snooping.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/248164/relationship-between-dot-doh-and-https

Comment: Any working VPN will work. However, your dad will simply take your computer away.

Comment: He does, I can hide it well though, And I have alternative options, Thanks for helping!

Comment: I would recommend just booting Tails or alternatively using Tor

Comment: @SirMuffington Tails is a bit of a nuclear option that definitely doesn't help if OP is at risk of losing computer privileges if dad catches them trying to hide their traffic.

Answer (score 2):

There are in fact 2 different questions here:

- can you hide your actual usage of the WiFi network from the local admin (your dad)?

  Of course you can, that is what VPN or Tor are made for: any local spy will only see your VPN entry point
- can you hide the fact that you are trying to circumvent the security rules (your dad spying on you)?

  The answer is no. And if I was your dad, first usage of a VPN would lead to: "Please stop that kind of game. I want to be able to control your network usage, full stop." And second try will just lead to confiscation of your box...

Never forget that outcomes of your actions in the virtual world can reach the real world.

Comment: Excellent answer, +1.  OP, with regard to the second question above, you might want to consider using TOR Bridges to hide the fact that you are using TOR from someone censoring or monitoring your networking activity.  See https://tb-manual.torproject.org/bridges/ and https://support.torproject.org/censorship/censorship-7/ for more info.